# TextBlock does not display all Text

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am new to this forum and new to windows phone 8 development.

I have below code

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#EEF8E5" Loaded="LayoutRoot_Loaded">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="20,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Text="فرآن کریم"/>

        <ScrollViewer  Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      x:Name="Scroller"  VerticalContentAlignment="Top" >
            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="20,0,0,0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="70"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtBismullah" FontSize="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txt" FontSize="40" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="Silver" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Button Content="1" Width="100" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

and c#

```
string readData()
        {
            string suraIndex = string.Empty;
            int counter = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
                suraIndex += counter++ + Environment.NewLine;
            return suraIndex;

        }
```

and finally

```
txt.Text += readData();
txt.Text += " I am Here";
```

The prob is, It does not show all the text, It shows only upto 35 (while there is a scroll because of scroller) but no text is displayed.

I dont know what is wrong with textblock and or may be its height, though it's set to Auto.

Comment: If you solved your own problem, post it as an answer so that people can see that as a proper question and answer.

Comment: Sorry, Not solved Yet. (I will remove the solved :()

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `TextBlock` in a `ScrollViewer` instead of the whole `Grid`

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="20,0,0,0">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <TextBlock x:Name="txtBismullah" FontSize="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0"/>
  <ScrollViewer x:Name="Scroller" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" >
    <TextBlock x:Name="txt" FontSize="40" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I sorted it out by using listbox instead of textblock with hell lots of lines. (Appreciate your comment)

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out by using listbox instead of textblock.